# Creating URLs to launch Skype from react (SIP)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sip

I currently am refactoring an application that was written in PHP into React. One of the features of the app is that it has links that are able to open chats with groups of users on Skype For Business.

URLs in the app look something like this:

```
<a href="im:<sip:someone@mydomain.com><sip:someone2@mydomain.com> 
            <sip:someone3@mydomain.com><sip:someone4@mydomain.com>      

 Click here to chat with group A 
</a>
```

This link would open up a chat window in Skype with all the users listed in the href.

In React I'm having a hard time getting these links to work correctly.

I have tried using React Router Link to= as well as regular a href and they both just append to my apps URL and it ends up looking like this in the link:

http://localhost:3000/%3Csip:%me@mydomain.com%3E#im:

How can I render these links in React so that the link is recognized correctly?

Comment: This works just fine for me, even though you have 4 users inside your href. However, on a Mac, that link, when ran from localhost, with a simple `<a>` tag, even though there's a router, will try to open iMessage.

Comment: You can have multiple users in the href tag to launch a Skype window with multiple people in the chat. Interesting that it works on a mac unfortunately we are running in a Windows environment.

Comment: May want to tackle the issue of that thing openning up iMessage, even though I have Skype installed as well